# Move data from one table to other in one sql oracle query, no pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a situation where selected data needs to be moved from one table to other identical tables in a single query. I am not allowed to write a pl/SQL block.

```
insert into table1 value select * from table2 where id=1;
delete from table2 where id=1;
```

I can achieve this by firing above two query in a single transaction and exception handling.

Here I need to ensure perfect cut paste operation.

Is it possible to do so in one simple SQL?

Comment: Do you mean you want to do insert and delete in the same SQL query. If so then its not possible. However I can see the query you posted above will not work coz of syntax issue.

Comment: Simple answer no. Fire 2 queries.

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into table1 select * from table2 where id=1;
delete from table2 where id=1;
```

This is correct way of doing that in Oracle. I've just removed `value` as `values` is iincorrect here and you also don't need to have synonym here.

Run that in one transaction is what you want. And this ensures cut paste. There is no other way of doing that. Even if you would be able to write this as a one statement DB engine would execute such two statements. Please only ensure you do it in single transaction.

Comment: iincorrect is incorrect. and it's only allowing me to save edit at least 6 chars. please update

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem whith the queries you provide.It all happens in one transaction if you make sure you only issue a commit after the delete statement.

- The newly inserted records in table1 are not visible for others until
  you issue a commit.
- The deleted records in table2 remain visible for
  others until you issue a commit.